# Benefit of locking a database call

Tags: c#, locking

All the other operations like Delete and Update also have a lockobject around the database operation.

I asked my self what was the purpose of the author who wrote that code?

When user1 deletes a node which user2 want to update then a lock does not help because the update will result in ZERO affected rows.

So what is the purpose/benefit of a lock object dealing with a treeview in a multi-user area?

```
public void CreateTreeNode(TreeNode node)
{
    lock (_lockObject)
    {
        _database.Create(node);
    }
}
```

Comment: If that's the only lock, he's simply making sure that only one node at a time is in the process of creation.  Whether that's a good thing or a bad thing for your application, impossible to tell with just two lines of code.

Comment: No as I said the Delete and update also has a lock object

Comment: Same lock object? I can't see updating something in the middle of it being deleted on another thread s being a good thing... `lock` may not be the best choice for this, but some sort of thread safety seems in order there, conceptually.

Comment: " I can't see updating something in the middle of it being deleted on another thread s being a good thing... " Doing that without a lock will result in zero affected records as I already said. Maybe a ORM will havea different behavior do not know... What else instead of a lock should be taken then?

Comment: Seem like basic reader writer operations, IE multiple readers single writer.  A ReadWriterLockSlim might be better, as an optimization.  That works be faster, s to just zero rows affected, that may need to be handled s an exception; depending on what that means to the app.